# How to navigate through ICollectionView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

So I've got a basic view model that functions like so:

```
// The ICollectionVIew is what my ListBox binds to.
public ICollectionView UserView { get; set; }

// <signup> is a model that's populated from a database representing a signup table
private ObservableCollection<signup> _signup;

    public ObservableCollection<signup> Signup
    {
        get
        {

            return _signup;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_signup != value)
            {
                value = _signup;
            }

            OnPropertyChanged("Signup");
        }
    }

    // This is the constructor for the ViewModel
    public registrationVM()
    {
        // entity context Fills up the Model 
        context.signups.Load();
        // The below code fills up the ObservableCollection
        var query = context.signups;
        _signup = new ObservableCollection<signup>(query);

        // And the below code fills up the ICollectionView using the ObservableCollection
        UserView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_signup);

    }
```

So now instead of binding to the ObservableCollection, I can bind to the ICollection.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding UserView}" DisplayMemberPath="firstName" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}"/>
```

This works perfectly in terms of loading my information. But then now comes the issue of navigating. I bound my button Commands to the ViewModel,

```
<Button x:Name="next" Command="{Binding Next}"/>
```

And in it's execution Method:

```
    private object Next_CommandExecute(object param)
    {
        // 'UserView' Is the ICollectionView I declared earlier
        return UserView.MoveCurrentToNext();
    }
```

The problem is the button's function doesn't do anything. Same goes for the 'previous' Button. The on screen selected record doesn't change so I'm guessing there's something I'm doing wrong. What exactly is what I've been failing to figure out. Does anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that your `Next_CommandExecute` function has been called? (e.g. by breakpoint)

Comment: @Fratyx I'm pretty sure it's being called. I checked by putting a MessageBox in it's place and it poped up on button click. Even if I put the command in the constructor, Nothing happens... To be honest though, I bave no clue what a breakpoint is...

Comment: Try to set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true` on your `ListBox`

Comment: @michaelmoore Kindly put that as an answer so I can mark it. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035241/how-to-navigate-through-icollectionview#comment42592836_27035241), you need to set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true` on your `ListBox`

```
ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding UserView}" 
        DisplayMemberPath="firstName"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true 
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}"/>
```